# Parsing rules with multiple AND and OR using ANTLR4?

Tags: antlr4

I am new to ANTLR4, and I am trying to use this to parse rule strings that we get from an external rules generator. 
The rules are of the form [attribute operator value(s)] ANDed and ORed multiple times.

I am able to parse the simpler ones such as:-

```
[divison3__c == ('AH Marketing', 'Asset Protection Solutions')]  OR  [hrstatus__c == ('Active')]
```

However, once I am struggling with ones that have compounded ANDs and ORs such as:-

```
[[divison3__c == ('AH Marketing', 'Asset Protection Solutions')] OR  [hrstatus__c == ('Active')]] AND [[hiredate__c > ('2000-01-01')] OR [custom10__c == ('ABCD')]]
```

My grammar that works for the simple rule is mentioned below. I would really appreciate any pointers about what needs to be done in terms of parsing the rules consisting of compound ANDs and ORs.

```
// Our grammar is called Rules.
grammar Rules;

// Rules
start: grouprules;

grouprules: grouprule (andor grouprule)* EOF;

grouprule: L_SB expression R_SB;

expression: USERATTRIBUTE operator values;

operator: EQ | NE | GE | GT | LE | LT;

values: '(' value  (','  value )* ')';

value: STRING | date;

date: '\'' DATE '\'';

andor: AND | OR;

// Tokens
EQ: '==';
NE: '!=';
GT:  '>';
GE: '>=';
LT:  '<';
LE: '<=';
L_SB: '[';
R_SB: ']';
AND: [aA][nN][dD];
OR: [oO][rR];
NUMBER: [0-9]+;

USERATTRIBUTE: [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*;

STRING:  '\'' ~('"')* '\'' ;

// Not perfect
DATE: [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-1][0-9][-][0-3][0-9] ;

// WS represents a whitespace, which is ignored entirely by skip.
WS: [ \t\u000C\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

---

Rule:

```
[divison3__c == ('AH Marketing', 'Asset Protection Solutions')]  OR  [hrstatus__c == ('Active')]
```

Successful Result:

```
(grouprules (grouprule [ [ hiredate__c (operator >) (values ( (value '2000-01-01')] AND [divison3__c == ('AH Marketing', 'Asset Protection Solutions') )) ]) ] <EOF>)
```

Compound Rule:

```
[[divison3__c == ('AH Marketing', 'Asset Protection Solutions')] OR  [hrstatus__c == ('Active')]] AND [[hiredate__c > ('2000-01-01')] OR [custom10__c == ('ABCD')]]
```

Unsuccessful Result:

```
line 1:1 extraneous input '[' expecting USERATTRIBUTE
line 1:162 extraneous input ']' expecting {<EOF>, AND, OR}
(grouprules (grouprule [ (expression [ divison3__c (operator ==) (values ( (value 'AH Marketing', 'Asset Protection Solutions')] OR  [hrstatus__c == ('Active')]] AND [[hiredate__c > ('2000-01-01')] OR [custom10__c == ('ABCD') ))) ]) ] <EOF>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of remarks about your grammar:

- your `STRING` should probably contain `~('\'')*` instead of `~('"')*`
- input like `'2018-12-31'` will not be  (partly) matched by your `DATE` rule: since it has quotes around it, your `STRING` rule would match it. `DATE` should probably be removed
- because of the previous remark, your `date` should be removed

This ought to do the trick:

```
grammar Grammar;

start
 : expr EOF
 ;

expr
 : USERATTRIBUTE ( EQ | NE | GE | GT | LE | LT ) expr
 | expr ( AND | OR ) expr
 | '[' expr ']'
 | list
 ;

list
 : '(' STRING  (','  STRING )* ')'
 ;

EQ : '==';
NE : '!=';
GT :  '>';
GE : '>=';
LT :  '<';
LE : '<=';
L_SB : '[';
R_SB : ']';
AND : [aA][nN][dD];
OR : [oO][rR];
NUMBER : [0-9]+;
USERATTRIBUTE : [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*;
STRING : '\'' ~('\'')* '\'' ;
WS : [ \t\u000C\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

Your input `[divison3__c == ('AH Marketing', 'Asset Protection Solutions')]  OR  [hrstatus__c == ('Active')]` gets parsed like this:

[image]

And `[[divison3__c == ('AH Marketing', 'Asset Protection Solutions')] OR  [hrstatus__c == ('Active')]] AND [[hiredate__c > ('2000-01-01')] OR [custom10__c == ('ABCD')]]` like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This really worked the trick. I am just fascinated about ANTLR4. So much to learn in this world. I get the idea now, and would now would be able to build my parser. Thank you so much! Unfortunately, I up voted both answers, but due to the fact that I have less than 15 votes they are not appearing.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't that you have multiple and/or operators (something like `[...] AND [...] OR [...]` would parse fine), but that there's nested brackets (`[[`). Currently your grammar only allows `USERATTRIBUTE operator values` inside brackets, not other brackets or `AND`/`OR`.

To allow this you should add `grouprules` as an alternative to `expression`, so an expression can not only have the form `USERATTRIBUTE operator values`, but also be a nested application of the `AND` and/or `OR` operators.

For this to work you need to first move the `EOF` from `grouprules` to `start` though as you won't want it to apply to nested `grouprules` inside brackets (since those will be followed by a closing bracket, not the end of file, which obviously only occurs once).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I made the changes as you mentioned. Now the errors have gone, but seems like testing with the alias 'grun' with -tree it is only parsing the first occurrence of the expression in the rule.  Added the result in the next comment. I will keep on trying.

Comment: [[divison3__c == ('AH Marketing', 'Asset Protection Solutions')] OR  [hrstatus__c == ('Active')]] AND [[hiredate__c > ('2000-01-01')] OR [custom10__c == ('ABCD')]]

Comment: (grouprules (grouprule [ (expression (grouprules (grouprule [ (expression divison3__c (operator ==) (values ( (value 'AH Marketing', 'Asset Protection Solutions')] OR  [hrstatus__c == ('Active')]] AND [[hiredate__c > ('2000-01-01')] OR [custom10__c == ('ABCD') ))) ]))) ]))

Comment: @SouvikMajumdar I may be missing something, but your output seems to include everything that was in your input, so it looks correct to me.